# Re-Order UITableView Sections only

Tags: ios

I have been trying to find some way to re-oder table sections by drag and drop exactly like [re-ordering table rows](https://www.raywenderlich.com/63089/cookbook-moving-table-view-cells-with-a-long-press-gesture) but no success. can someone guide me where to go? I only need to re order complete section not some rows.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way with the standard delegate methods

- Implement `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`
  `data` represents the data source array containing the sections.

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     let itemToMove = data[sourceIndexPath.section]
     data.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.section)
     data.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.section)
     tableView.reloadData()
   }
  ```
- Set `editing` of the table view to `true`. The reorder symbol appears.
- Drag a row. The code in method `moveRowAtIndexPath` reorders the entire section.